# Error in GitHub Action when Building xArchive

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, github-actions

So I am trying to create a pipeline in Github Action that will build the app, and I am stuck at this point on this command (I just changed the team id and uuid and team name into ):

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -configuration Release DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=<TEAM> -sdk 'iphoneos' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath build-output/app.xcarchive PROVISIONING_PROFILE=<UUID> clean archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="Apple Distribution: <TEAM_NAME>"
```

I am getting this error:

> error: No profile for team '' matching 'Accept AppStore Profile'
> found: Xcode couldn't find any provisioning profiles matching
> '/Accept AppStore Profile'. Install the profile (by dragging and
> dropping it onto Xcode's dock item) or select a different one in the
> Signing & Capabilities tab of the target editor. (in target 'Runner'
> from project 'Runner')

So I tried to run this script to install the profile:

- https://gist.githubusercontent.com/benvium/2568707/raw/19a4f31db299a30a7b948742deb876ad7bcd0cf4/installMobileProvisionFile.sh

and Also I am using this article as a guide for my pipeline:

- https://damienaicheh.github.io/flutter/github/actions/2021/04/22/build-sign-flutter-ios-github-actions-en.html

But still no luck, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same issue.